# How to create foreign keys in gorm v2?

Tags: go, foreign-keys, go-gorm

I am trying to create foreign key in Gorm v2. Lets say I have these 2 models.

```
type User struct{
    ID uint
    Name string
    TicketID uint
}

type Ticket struct{
   ID uint
   Code uuid.UUID
}
```

How do I denote the `User(TicketID)` as foreign key when using Gorm v2. I used to be able to use the function `AddForeignKey()` but its no longer there in Gorm v2.

Comment: now you have to use db.Migrator().CreateConstraint() its in their release note https://gorm.io/docs/v2_release_note.html

Comment: i have used db.Migrator().CreateConstraint() and it ran fine without errors but when i ran `SHOW KEYS FROM users` or `SHOW KEYS FROM tickets` in terminal, this constraint does not show up. I am not sure if the constraint is just not gonna be shown or not being created at all. anw thanks for the reply.